# Need to make a layout Like this but getting confused

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am just developing an Android application for that I need to create a layout like this.

[image]

I tried **Horizontal Scroll** but I Don't know how to make those navigation button with dots showing focused button in the middle

something like this [image]

Answer (score 0):

// try this

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: yes i already try this method but it didn't look right. I need to include those 2 navigation button with those tiny dots indicating the focused button

Comment: no I just want to display ImageButton on click of which i move to next activity

Answer (score 0):

checkout this `https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html`

and use `https://github.com/ongakuer/CircleIndicator` for circle indicator

Comment: yes  you can control the view pager with image button but i am not sure about circle indicator just give it a try

Comment: viewPager controls the multiple fragment but here I just want to show imageButton. If I want to add 100 ImageButton then I have to create 100 fragment which is not good I Think

Comment: have you play the game (tap the frog)  I want exact layout.